# LXDE autostart script runs repeatedly

Tags: raspbian-buster, bash, lxde

I added the following line to my /etc/xdg/LXDE-pi/autostart:

`@bash '/pi/startService.sh'`

My startService.sh is opening an AppImage.
However after closing the App it seems like the script is executed again and my App opens up again. After closing it 5-6x it stays closed.

Is this normal behavior? What would I need to do so that the Script doesn’t restart when the user closes the App that was launched?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by removing the @ in front of the bash. Now it executes the script only once and doesn’t restart anymore when I close the app.

Hope this will help somebody in the future.